# Update example comment in Tour

Tags: feature-request, comments, help-center

I know we've been working a lot lately on trying to get comments more in line with the guidelines, in particular keeping them to concrete requests for clarification and limiting the amount of discussion. Another recent conversation on comments made me go look at our [Tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what it had to say on comments. I noticed that the example screenshot it gives doesn't really fit with the way we view comments now.

[image: screenshot of comment section from tour]

Would it be possible to change this sample to be of some useful constructive comments so as to be a better example for our new members?

Comment: True, the sample comment is ironically flag-worthy... however, I feel this could apply to all SE sites, don't you think? (*goes to check out other tours *)

Comment: The tour has some pretty harsh restrictions for questions that can be used, too.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/162102.  Please feel free to propose better questions that fit the criteria!  And if the only problem with a question is that some comment cleanup is needed, we can address that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio given how hard it is to control comments (as opposed to questions and answers) I would say a proper solution would be to just suppress showing comments. As they say in the very [tour] we discuss, "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions"

Comment: ...as sort of follow-up, I posted feature request at MSE: [Hide comments (if there are any) in the example posts selected for the Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315594/165773)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oh, I wasn't paying attention enough to notice that all of the examples were from the same question. I can definitely see how that would make it harder to find one. And really, "useful" comments should be removed once they have been addressed, so that makes it even more challenging to find a good, short question with good, short answers and helpful comments.